# Azure ARM template executing two custom script extension on same VM

Tags: azure

How do i deploy two custom script extension on same VM using ARM template, for example one script i am installing Domain controller on the VM upon reboot i want to execute one more script that creates domain user accounts. its throwing me error right now if i have two extension depends on same VM

```
"Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'PrimaryDCVMPostDeploy' with handler 'Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension' already added or specified in input"
```

Thanks for any help!
Sri

Comment: try to use the same name when you deploy two custom script extensions?

Comment: no they both have different names, but one have to execute after another after the Virtual machine boots up.. so first script install domain controllerservices next script suppose to create domain users.. but ARM template throw this error.

Comment: Check the update portion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531526/how-to-run-a-2-vm-custom-script-extensions-on-azure-vm-at-the-same-time